# Table Column Reorder material ui, React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table, material-ui

I need to implement Column Reordering Feature in a Material Ui Table. Table code is given below. There is a button in the UI "Reorder Column". When user click on that button a Drawer wii open having the Drag and Drop option (column option). I have to reorder table column from there. Could you please help me to do this? Advance thanks.

```
           <TableContainer>
          <Table sx={{ minWidth: 700 }}>
         <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell>
                  <Checkbox
                    checked={selectTopCheckbox}
                    onChange={(e) => handleAllCheckbox(e)}
                    indeterminate={showIndeterminate}
                  />
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>Registered Name</TableCell>
                <TableCell>Application No</TableCell>
                <TableCell>Form Name</TableCell>
                <TableCell>Registered Email</TableCell>
                <TableCell>Registered Mobile</TableCell>

                <TableCell>Payment Status</TableCell>
                {customizeColumnOptions?.checkedApplicationDate ? (
                  <TableCell>Application Date</TableCell>
                ) : null}
                {customizeColumnOptions?.checkedState ? (
                  <TableCell>State</TableCell>
                ) : null}
                {customizeColumnOptions?.checkedCity ? (
                  <TableCell>City</TableCell>
                ) : null}
                {customizeColumnOptions?.checkedCounselorName ? (
                  <TableCell>Counselor</TableCell>
                ) : null}
                {customizeColumnOptions?.checkedSource ? (
                  <TableCell>Source</TableCell>
                ) : null}
                {customizeColumnOptions?.checkedApplicationStage ? (
                  <TableCell>Application Stage</TableCell>
                ) : null}
                {customizeColumnOptions?.checkedLeadStage ? (
                  <TableCell>Lead Stage</TableCell>
                ) : null}
                {customizeColumnOptions?.checkedLeadType ? (
                  <TableCell>Lead Type</TableCell>
                ) : null} */}
            {/* {course ? <TableCell>Course</TableCell> : null}
                   {utmPay ? <TableCell>Utm Payment</TableCell> : null} */}
            {/* <TableCell>Action</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>



           
            <TableBody>
              {applications.map((dataRow) => {

                return (
                  <TableRow key={dataRow.application_id}>
                    <TableCell>
                      <Checkbox
                        checked={
                          selectedApplications?.includes(
                            dataRow?.application_id
                          )
                            ? true
                            : false
                        }
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          handleApplicationCheckBox(
                            e,
                            dataRow?.application_id,
                            dataRow?.student_email_id
                          );
                        }}
                      />
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>
                      <Box sx={{ display: "flex", alignItem: "center" }}>
                        <Avatar sx={{ width: 42, height: 42 }}>
                          {dataRow?.student_name?.slice(0, 1)}
                        </Avatar>
                        <Box sx={{ ml: 1 }}>
                          <Box
                            onClick={() =>
                              navigate("/userProfile", {
                                state: {
                                  applicationId: dataRow?.application_id,
                                  studentId: dataRow?.student_id,
                                  courseName: dataRow?.course_name,
                                },
                              })
                            }
                          >
                            <Link to="">
                              <Typography variant="subtitle2">
                                {dataRow?.student_name ? dataRow?.student_name : `– –`}
                              </Typography>
                            </Link>
                          </Box>
                          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">
                            {dataRow?.student_email_id ? dataRow?.student_email_id : `– –`}
                          </Typography>
                        </Box>
                      </Box>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>
                      {dataRow?.custom_application_id
                        ? dataRow?.custom_application_id
                        : `– –`}
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{dataRow?.course_name ? dataRow?.course_name : `– –`}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{dataRow?.student_email_id ? dataRow?.student_email_id : `– –`}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{dataRow?.student_mobile_no ? dataRow?.student_mobile_no : `– –`}</TableCell>

                    <TableCell>
                      {dataRow?.payment_status
                        ? dataRow?.payment_status
                        : `– –`}
                    </TableCell>
                    {
                      customizeColumnOptions?.checkedApplicationDate &&
                      <TableCell>
                        {dataRow?.date ? dataRow?.date : `– –`}
                      </TableCell>
                    }

                    {customizeColumnOptions?.checkedState && (
                      <TableCell>
                        {dataRow?.state_name ? dataRow?.state_name : `– –`}
                      </TableCell>
                    )}
                    {customizeColumnOptions?.checkedCity && (
                      <TableCell>
                        {dataRow?.city_name ? dataRow?.city_name : `– –`}
                      </TableCell>
                    )}
                    {customizeColumnOptions?.checkedCounselorName && (
                      <TableCell>
                        {dataRow?.counselor_name
                          ? dataRow?.counselor_name
                          : `– –`}
                      </TableCell>
                    )}
                    {customizeColumnOptions?.checkedSource && (
                      <TableCell>
                        {dataRow?.source_name ? dataRow?.source_name : `– –`}
                      </TableCell>
                    )}
                    {customizeColumnOptions?.checkedApplicationStage && (
                      <TableCell>
                        {dataRow?.application_status
                          ? dataRow?.application_status
                          : `– –`}
                      </TableCell>
                    )}
                    {customizeColumnOptions?.checkedLeadStage && (
                      <TableCell>
                        {dataRow?.lead_stage ? dataRow?.lead_stage : `– –`}
                      </TableCell>
                    )}
                    {customizeColumnOptions?.checkedLeadType && (
                      <TableCell>
                        {dataRow?.lead_type ? dataRow?.lead_type : `– –`}
                      </TableCell>
                    )}

                    {/* {course && <TableCell>{dataRow.course}</TableCell>}
            {utmPay && <TableCell>{dataRow.utmPay}</TableCell>} */}
                    <TableCell>
                      <IconButton>
                        <Download
                          onClick={() =>
                            handleSingleApplicationDownload(
                              dataRow?.application_id
                            )
                          }
                        />
                      </IconButton>
                    </TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                );
              })}
              {/* {emptyRows > 0 && (
        <TableRow>
          <TableCell colSpan={6} />
        </TableRow>
      )} */}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
```

Comment: you can use 'react-beautiful-dnd' package to change the sequence of the columns in the array and then update the column with the new array and once the state is updated table will re-render you got your columns re-ordered! sandbox example for reordering array https://codesandbox.io/s/k260nyxq9v

Comment: @SatyamSaurabh Could you please give me a example of functional component? thanks

Comment: here I updated the component to functional component https://codesandbox.io/s/vertical-list-forked-374iw4?file=/index.js